# VScode does not highlight the modified line

Tags: visual-studio-code, codehighlighter

I have one big trouble with VSCode, it does not highlight the modified line. I use version 1.76.1 on Win 10

**I would like to see where the line number is that this line has a change**
[image]

Comment: What highlight are you expecting and why?  For example, are you expecting it to highlight changes from the unmodified source control?  What source control are you using?  What VSCode extension(s) are you using to manage that source control?  Or are you expecting some other highlight?  Please clarify.

Comment: I would like to see where the line number is that this line has a change

Comment: Is this an initialized Git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the same issue by switching back to version 1.75.1 (it's a temporary fix until VS Code releases an update)